# ¿Cómo se fusionan dos marcos de datos utilisando la columna de fechas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, sum

Tengo dos dataframes y me gustaria mergerlas sobre las fechas

```
>>>df_ga.head()

    Month Index Count   Created At
0   0.0         70      2018-09-01
1   1.0         254     2018-10-01
2   2.0         231     2018-11-01
3   3.0         261     2018-12-01
4   4.0         265     2019-01-01

>>> df_sum.head()
    Created At  Count
32  2018-11-01  327
31  2018-12-01  424
29  2019-01-01  596
28  2019-02-01  615
18  2019-03-01  1147
```

Entonces intenté:

```
>>>df = pd.merge(df_ga, df_sum, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True, on='Created At')
df


    Count_x Created At  Count_y
0   70  2018-09-01  4790
1   254 2018-10-01  4641
2   231 2018-11-01  4208
3   261 2018-12-01  4039
4   265 2019-01-01  3649
5   834 2019-02-01  3490
6   472 2019-03-01  3207
7   511 2019-04-01  2708
8   531 2019-05-01  2491
9   516 2019-06-01  2427
10  530 2019-07-01  2095
11  885 2019-08-01  2030
12  835 2019-09-01  1748
13  925 2019-10-01  1697
14  927 2019-11-01  1640
15  930 2019-12-01  1422
16  1,328   2020-01-01  1267
17  2,795   2020-02-01  1191
18  3,128   2020-03-01  1147
19  2,471   2020-04-01  1139
20  2,013   2020-05-01  1110
21  2,121   2020-06-01  1102
22  2,149   2020-07-01  1090
23  2,840   2020-08-01  1025
24  3,504   2020-09-01  666
25  3,029   2020-10-01  657
26  2,114   2020-11-01  649
27  2,244   2020-12-01  638
28  2,978   2021-01-01  615
29  2,771   2021-02-01  596
30  2,273   2021-03-01  587
31  2,390   2021-04-01  424
32  1,173   2021-05-01  327
```

Como se puede ver,

- por un lado los `Count` de `df_sum` no se transfieren correctamente a la columna `Count_y`. En efecto todo está al revés. Por ejemplo, el primero en `df_sum` es `2018-11-01 = 327` pero en `df` se encuentra asignado a la última fecha:`2021-05-01`
- y por otro lado crea datos para esta columna en fechas que no existen en `df_sum`. Por ejemplo no hay `2018-09-01`.

Comment: lo he probado y todo sale correcto :/

Comment: ¿Es así @Christian ? Acabo de probarlo y como puedes ver en `df` todo los Count de `df_sum` sale al revés. Los primeros resultados son los últimos y los últimos se convierten en los primeros

Comment: puedes verlo [aquí](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EJygBi37W1Oe8bFEFqJlMijeejmp_0E3?usp=sharing)

Comment: Oh sí, efectivamente, es súper raro, comparto el mío [aquí](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IvV-4ImWi3QUthDH1DOTwm6PahQky01n?authuser=0#scrollTo=2c26Zz9sbJ5p) @Christian

Comment: como sabrás los archivos subidos a colab se borran por lo que no puedo probarlo realmente. De igual forma es un poco raro, pero en vez de hacer `df.head()` solo haz `df` y mira que imprime

Comment: Si por desgracia @Christian Ok, acabo de cambiar veo que `Count_y` se ordena numéricamente en orden descendente en lugar de por fecha